# jQuery lite: find() animating issue?

Tags: jquery, angularjs-directive

When applying the following in an Angular directive the refresh icon animates for one second and then stops, that's fine no problem there. The problem occurs when applying additional items as all the images animate in parallel when all I want is the first to animate.

```
var img = element.find('img'); <-- I suspect this is incorrect
img.addClass('animate');
setTimeout( function() {
  img.removeClass('animate');
}, 1000);    


<!-- HTML TEMPLATE -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="listItemContainer">
            <img class="refreshIcon" src="images/refresh.png">
            <div class="classA">{{item.prop1}}</div>
            <div class="classB">{{item.prop2}}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is `element`? i suspect it's not the latest added element, but instead, some parent element.

Comment: Hi Kevin, it's a 'div' <div animated-list></div>

Comment: In that case you'll need to filter the selection after .find to the first one. (for example, `.eq(0)`)

Comment: Simple when you know how, thanks Kevin that worked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

.find() will find all of the images, not just the first one. To filter down to the first, simply add `.eq(0)` after `.find()`

```
var img = element.find('img').eq(0);
```